# Draw screenshot of Silverlight application using Visio?

Tags: silverlight

Is there any way I could draw screenshot design of Silverlight application using Visio?

Or any other tool I could use to draw screenshot of Silverlight application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but here are two answers:

If you're looking for an application to create a **mock-up design** of a Silverlight application, I'd recommend using Expression Blend 3 (version 3 or greater) with Sketch Flow.  Sketch Flow allows you to create a real "sketch" of a user interface that can later be turned into a Silverlight application.  It's great for application design purposes.

You can also use Powerpoint, Excel, Access or other Office applications to make rough sketches of application flow, but these usually appear really crude.

If you're looking to **take screen shots of existing Silverlight applications**, I'd recommend Jing (free), SnagIt ($), or the free Snipping Tool in Windows 7 or Vista.

Comment: I was looking for something that I could create the mock-up design.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The best mock-up design tool I have ever used (and still use almost every day) is [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups).